# How to auto-remove Docker container while persisting logs?

Tags: docker

Is there any way to use Docker's `--rm` option that auto-removes the container once it exits but allow the container's logs to persist?

I have an application that creates containers to process jobs, and then once all jobs are complete, the container exits and is deleted to conserve space. However, in case a bug caused the container's process to exit prematurely, I'd like to persist the log files so I can confirm it exited cleanly or diagnose a faulty exit.

However, the `--rm` option appears to remove the container's logs along with the container.

Answer (score 0):

Log to somewhere outside of the container.

1. You could mount a directory of the host in your container, so logs will be written to the host directory and kept after rm.
2. Or you can mount a volume on your container; which will be persisted after rm
3. Or you can setup rsyslog - or some similar log collection agent - to export your logs to a remote service. See https://www.simulmedia.com/blog/2016/02/19/centralized-docker-logging-with-rsyslog/ for more on this solution.

The first 2 are hacks but easier to get up and running on your workstation/server. If this is all cloud hosted there might be a decent log offloading option (Cloudwatch on AWS) which saves you the hassle of configuring rsyslog